# How to setup the selenium driver's path in the constructor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I'm so sorry to ask such a trivial question. This is how I'm accessing the a file in my local machine.

```
public static readonly IWebDriver WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium\Chrome");
```

Now, I'd like to place the file in one of the folder inside the solution when I deploy the code. How should I modify the path to the file?

The new location will be inside a folder called **Selenium**, which in turns, will be inside another folder called **Shared**.

I changed the path to:

```
public static readonly IWebDriver WebDriver = 
                              new ChromeDriver("/Share/Selenium/Chrome");
```

Now I'm getting an exception. I'm sure that has to do with the way I setup the path.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
public static readonly IWebDriver WebDriver = 
                              new ChromeDriver("./Share/Selenium/Chrome");
```

Since, you have not defined the root/current directory it does not know where to start from.

Comment: I tried `./Share/Selenium/Chrome`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you draw the directory structure somehow and share?

Comment: Here is the structure of the pathe `QaAutomation/QaPageObject/Share/selenium/Chrome`, with `QaAutomation` as the solution, `QaPageObject` as the project, and `Share`, `Selenium`, and `Chrome` being just folders. One thing I should add is that I'm working in Visual Studio

Comment: @Richard77 Just curious since, you are using C# with Visual studio. Is there any reason you are not using Nuget Package manager? That reduces a lot of headache

Comment: You are right. I'll try nuget. The only problem is that there are 3 drivers, one for firefox, one for IE, and one for Chrome. However, nuget manager is displaying. Nuget gives me only the default one, i.e. the driver that works with Firefox.

Comment: I manage all three through NuGet. What do you mean by **Nuget gives me only the default one,**?

Comment: I found a suitable version in Nuget. `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/` I even installed it already, but I don't see any reference when I expend the References node.

Comment: @Richard77 Can you provide a screenshot/screencast ?